# Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "CONCAT_WS" at [2:1]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

"CONCAT_WS (‘ . ’, ‘www’, ‘google’, ‘com’)

*The separator (being the period) gets input before and after Google when you run the SQL function"
Tried to use this function big-query, but received an error.
If we're not able to use this function on big-query, then how can we add the period before and after google in google_big_query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't support `concat_ws()`, but it is easy to emulate using arrays:

```
select array_to_string(array['www', 'google', 'com'], '.')
```

Note that this has the same semantics as `concat_ws()` in that it ignores `NULL` values.  So the above and the following both return `'www.google.com'`:

```
select array_to_string(array[NULL, 'www', NULL, 'google', 'com'], '.')
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.  Would you be kind to answer the question I have with the second syntax.  -- select array_to_string(array[NULL, 'www', NULL, 'google', 'com'], '.')                                                 --Here why there is no NULL in-between 'google' and 'com'. It can be included??

Comment: @sathyanarayanan . . . That is actually considered a *feature*.  In any case, if you wanted `NULL` to be in the string, you would need use have `'NULL'` as a string, not the `NULL` value.